# when use javassist to create a method, how to assign generic class int method return type?

Tags: generics, javassist

I want to use javassist to create a method like this:

```
public List<String> queryList(Long id) { return new ArrayList<String>();}
```

but, how to assign the generic class type "String" to List?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. See [javassist documentation](http://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial3.html#generics):

> The generics of Java is implemented by the erasure technique. After
>   compilation, all type parameters are dropped off. For example, suppose
>   that your source code declares a parameterized type Vector:

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
  :
String s = v.get(0);
```

> The compiled bytecode is equivalent to the following code:

```
Vector v = new Vector();
  :
String s = (String)v.get(0);
```

So, your method after compilation would look like below:

```
public List queryList(Long id) { return new ArrayList();}
```

Behind the scene there is a casting to required type if needed. See also: [Type Erasure in Java Explained](https://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `setGenericSignature()` of `CtBehavior`:

```java
method.setGenericSignature("(Ljava/util/List<Ljava/lang/Long;>;)V");
```

In contrast to `getSignature()` the method `getGenericSignature()` will then return a `String` that contains the types in the generic parameters.
However, the compiler does not have to set this information. Hence; this is an optional information.